# Why are we not allowed to give comment for a question or an answer?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

By reading some questions, I came to know that I should have get at least 50 reputation. But we have some minor doubts in the answers given by potential users. For that we don't want to post a question(duplicate to same) again due to inability to give comment. We are newbies and we don't have much reputation to do that.

I faced this issue so many times but nothing to do. Should we post unnecessary questions to get the reputations so that we can give comment or questions to a specific thread?

Is there any way to decrease the reputation count to ask a comment?

Example: @Mike, Hi mike, There is a question [Adding users to sudoers through shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784761/adding-users-to-sudoers-through-shell-script?answertab=active#tab-top) and it was replied by WChargin. It didn't worked for me so I thought to give comment on that with the error description I have got. (But I am not able to give comment)

If I ask the same question again, I may not be able to get the attention from the same potential replier(Wchargin). If I give comment to the same answer, I am sure he will give suggestion to that.

Comment: If it is your question, you can post comments, no problem.

Comment: Asking questions isn't the only way to earn reputation. You can post answers or suggest edits.

Comment: But there are similar questions answered by many other. In that scenario, we have to just confirm by commenting(asking) to it. Should I post the question again in that small scenario?

Comment: @Gamecat its not a duplicate...

Comment: Maybe you can give us a short example? If you post the title of your proposed question and how it differs from an existing question I'm sure you'll get much better feedback about the appropriate action.

Comment: @MikeB, edited the post to give an example

Comment: After reading your edit I think the best course of action would be to create a new question, reference the question you followed, and detail the error message you received. This new question would be about the error message you got and referencing the other question will help others understand how you arrived at this point. Kind of like this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844348/follow-up-viewdidunload-vs-dealloc-question

Answer (score 1):

If you have a follow on question, something that is different from the question you are looking at, by all means, ask a new question.

When asking, link to the original to give some context and explain in detail you new question (including what you have tried, what you don't understand and code if you have some).

Comment: will I get the attention of the same author answered for the previous question?

Comment: @Rajasekhar - No.